# Roundcube отображение квоты

Tags: roundcube

Настраиваю почтовый сервер, в качестве веб-морды поставил Roundcube, хочу чтобы у пользователей отображалась квота

[image: Roundcube квота]

настраивал по статье https://www.dmosk.ru/miniinstruktions.php?mini=quota-dovecot-postfixadmin

но квота не отображается.